# Get tableName values to be put into hashmap

Tags: java

I need to tablevalues.. into the map..
My code is bellow:

public HashMap getValuesFromDeleteAction(String tableName,Object[] filterColumn,Object[] filterValue){

```
    Connection conn = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            HashMap map = new HashMap();

            try{
                System.out.println("====DELETE_ACTION===");
                conn=this.getConnection();
                if(conn!=null && !conn.isClosed()){
                        if(filterColumn!=null && filterValue!=null && !tableName.trim().isEmpty()
                                &&filterColumn.length==filterValue.length){
                         String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+tableName+"";    
                         String filterSql = " WHERE " ;
                            for(int i=0;i<filterColumn.length;i++){
                                if(i==0){
                                 filterSql = filterColumn[i]+"="+"'"+filterValue[i]+"'";
                                }else{
                                    filterSql= filterSql+" AND "+filterColumn[i]+"="+"'"+filterValue[i]+"'";                                    }
                                 }
                        String sSql=sql+filterSql;
                        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sSql);
                        rs=ps.executeQuery();
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                            map.put(tableName +"LAST_UPDATE_DATE", rs.getString("LAST_UPDATE_DATE"));
                            map.put(tableName +"LAST_UPDATE_BY" , rs.getString("LAST_UPDATE_BY"));
                        }
                        }else{
                        //do nothing
                     }
                    System.out.println("MapValues==2323===>"+map);

               }
            }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return map;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need `else` here.

Answer (score 0):

first define your map by this:

```
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and where is your connection settings!?

then try this:

```
while(rs.next()) {
 map.put("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", rs.getString("LAST_UPDATE_DATE"));
 map.put("LAST_UPDATE_BY", rs.getString("LAST_UPDATE_BY"));
}
```

Comment: Super Hornet.. i find the solution about that.. because i made mistakes in defines the filter column and filtervalues.. that's why.. thank you so much